# отображение скрытых данных через scrollTop. Имитация ленивой загрузки

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка, lazyloading

Накидал код отображения данных, по событию $(window).scroll(). Все работает хорошо, за исключением одного момента. Скрипт срабатывает только 1 раз. Т.е. загрузиться 10 блоков и все на этом. Спускаю еще раз ниже скроллбар и ничего не происходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что поменять?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.blog_content:lt(10)').css("display", "flex");
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
         if($(window).scrollTop() >= $("html").height()){
            setTimeout(function() {
                size_li = $(".blog_content").length;
               x=10;
               x=(x+10 <= size_li) ? x+10 : size_li;
               $('.blog_content:lt('+x+')').css("display", "flex");
            }, 1500);
         }
        
    });
});
```

```css
.blog_content {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="blog_content">
<p>Reference site about Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.</p>
</div>
<div class="blog_content">
<p>Reference site about Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.</p>
</div>
<div class="blog_content">
<p>Reference site about Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.</p>
</div>
<div class="blog_content">
<p>Reference site about Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.</p>
</div>
<div class="blog_content">
<p>Reference site about Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.</p>
</div>
<div class="blog_content">
<p>Reference site about Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.</p>
</div>
<div class="blog_content">
<p>Reference site about Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.</p>
</div>
<div class="blog_content">
<p>Reference site about Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.</p>
</div>
<div class="blog_content">
<p>Reference site about Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.</p>
</div>
<div class="blog_content">
<p>Reference site about Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.</p>
</div>
<div class="blog_content">
<p>Reference site about Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ничего не понятно...сделайте воспроизводимый пример

Comment: сделал как просили

Comment: у вас не заходит в условие...попробуйте так `if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height())`

Comment: событие все равно срабатывает только 1 раз